# ¿Cómo puedo con jQuery llamar una funcion anónima con un evento change(), que detecte el cambio del atributo value de un input?

Tags: jquery, funciones, function, callback

Estoy reicien iniciando en **jQuery** y quisiera ejecutar una funcion con evento `.change()`, ya que entiendo que `change()`se activa despues de que ocurre un cambio, pero  no sé hacer, que detecte el cambio de valor del `value=""` de un input.

Sé cómo cambiar el `value=""` del input con una funcion anónima con evento `click()` que da paso a ejecutar el evento `.val()` en el input, ésta ultima cambia el valor de `value=""`, y seguido, hay otra funcion que remueve elementos `html` repetidos, dejo aqui el ejemplo:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#id-div").click(function(){
    $('#id-input').val("algo-dos");
        var seen = {};
        $("p").each(function() {
        var txt = $(this).text(); 
        if (seen[txt]) 
        $(this).remove();
        else 
        seen[txt] = true;
      });
    });
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="clase-div" id="id-div">
        <input class="clase-input" type="text" id="id-input" value="algo-uno">
        <p>adios</p>
        <p>adios</p>
    </div>

    <div class="clase-div2">
      <p>hola</p>
      <p>hola</p>
      <p>holaa</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Lo que me gustaría hacer es que después de la funcion anónoma `click()`, que da paso al evento `.val()` sobre el input, seguido, se llame a la funcion anonima con evento `change()` y este detecte el cambio de valor del `value=""` del input, y que esto último de paso a la función que elimina elementos `html` repetidos, lo he intentado pero no me funciona, dejo el ejemplo:

```js
$(function() {
  var valor = $("#id-input").val();
  alert(valor);
  $("#id-div").click(function(){
    $('#id-input').val("algo-dos");
      alert(valor);
      $(valor).change(function(){
        var seen = {};
        $("p").each(function() {
        var txt = $(this).text(); 
        if (seen[txt]) 
        $(this).remove();
        else 
        seen[txt] = true;
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="clase-div" id="id-div">
        <input class="clase-input" type="text" id="id-input" value="algo-uno">
        <p>adios</p>
        <p>adios</p>
    </div>

    <div class="clase-div2">
      <p>hola</p>
      <p>hola</p>
      <p>holaa</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Como pueden ver he dejado puesto `alert()` para la variable `valor` que contiene el valor del `value=""` del input y este no cambia, y por eso `change()` no se ejecuta. ¿Me pueden ayudar a que si cambie `valor` para que `change()` lo detecte por favor?

Comment: a que se refiere "Supongo que esto se soluciona" ?

Comment: Quise decir que creo que es posible hacer que las funciones se llamen en orden, en mi caso necesitaria que primero se ejecute la funcion con el evento click(), luego la del evento change() y luego la que elimina etiqutas repetidas.

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara y el código compartido no parece  mostrar todo el contexto (hablas de dos llamadas y no veo esas dos llamadas en el código). De todos modos, lo más importante aquí es que tengas claro que Javascript es **asíncrono**, por tanto debes olvidarte de llamadas en cadena como puede ocurrir en otros lenguajes que pones en la línea `5` una llamada a `funciónA` y en la línea `6` otra llamada a `funciónB`. **En JS no es así, debes llamar a `funcionB` desde dentro de `funcionA` o bien implementar un callback**.

Comment: Ohhh creo que entiendo, voy a reformular mi pregunta